# Transform e position relative - Não funciona os 2!

Tags: css

Galerinha preciso de uma ajuda com o transform, e o position relative!
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mWNJjR
Aqui o botão funciona perfeito, quando você passa o mouse ele aumenta, usando o transform, mas não está centralizado e responsivo da forma que eu preciso.

```css
.playbuttondiv {
    position: absolute;
    top: 33%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) scale(1, 1);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) scale(1, 1);
 font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
 color: #222;
}

.playbutton {
    background-color: #31ae1f;
    z-index: -1;
 box-shadow: 0 4px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
 text-shadow: 0 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
 font-size: 36px;
 line-height: 39px;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 23px 23px 21px 23px;
 color: white;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
 border-top: 4px solid #64fd1f;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #1e8c03;
    border-left: 4px solid #156c00;
    border-right: 4px solid #47d009;
 font-weight: bold;
 position: fixed;
}

.playbutton:hover {
 background-color: #272727;
    border-top-color: #3d3d3d;
    border-bottom-color: #000;
    border-right-color: #2f2f2f;
    border-left-color: #171717;
 outline-offset: -2px;
 color: white;
 webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);

}
```

```html
  <div class="playbuttondiv">
            <a class="playbutton">Jogar</a>
        </div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ryXVrR
Aqui está com o position relative, centralizado e responsivo, da forma que eu preciso, mas o transform simplesmente não funciona, é ignorado.

```css
.playbuttondiv {
    position: absolute;
    top: 33%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) scale(1, 1);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) scale(1, 1);
 font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
 color: #222;
}

.playbutton {
    background-color: #31ae1f;
    z-index: -1;
 box-shadow: 0 4px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
 text-shadow: 0 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
 font-size: 36px;
 line-height: 39px;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 23px 23px 21px 23px;
 color: white;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
 border-top: 4px solid #64fd1f;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #1e8c03;
    border-left: 4px solid #156c00;
    border-right: 4px solid #47d009;
 font-weight: bold;
 position: relative;
}

.playbutton:hover {
 background-color: #272727;
    border-top-color: #3d3d3d;
    border-bottom-color: #000;
    border-right-color: #2f2f2f;
    border-left-color: #171717;
 outline-offset: -2px;
 color: white;
 webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);

}
```

```html
  <div class="playbuttondiv">
            <a class="playbutton">Jogar</a>
        </div>
```

Podem me dar uma ajuda? Preciso exatamente dos 2...

Answer (score 0):

Usa o `calc` para retirar metade do tamanho do button para centralizar: `top: calc(50% - 92px/2);` `left: calc(50% - 156px/2);` .

```css
.playbuttondiv {
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50% - 92px/2);
    left: calc(50% - 156px/2);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) scale(1, 1);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) scale(1, 1);
 font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
 color: #222;
}

.playbutton {
    background-color: #31ae1f;
    z-index: -1;
 box-shadow: 0 4px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
 text-shadow: 0 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
 font-size: 36px;
 line-height: 39px;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 23px 23px 21px 23px;
 color: white;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
 border-top: 4px solid #64fd1f;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #1e8c03;
    border-left: 4px solid #156c00;
    border-right: 4px solid #47d009;
 font-weight: bold;
 position: fixed;
}

.playbutton:hover {
 background-color: #272727;
    border-top-color: #3d3d3d;
    border-bottom-color: #000;
    border-right-color: #2f2f2f;
    border-left-color: #171717;
 outline-offset: -2px;
 color: white;
 webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);

}
```

```html
<div class="playbuttondiv">
  <a class="playbutton">Jogar</a>
</div>
```